# Entity Framework Code First : One-To-One association using Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-one

I am having .NET MVC 5 and Identity...
I am trying to get a one to one relationship for my Member class to my MemberInfo class..
So, My classes looks something like this:

IdentityUser is in the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework namespace with string Id as its ID.

```
public class GRNUser : IdentityUser {
    ....
    .... 
}


public class MemberUser : GRNUser {
    public virtual Member MemberInfo {get; set; }
}

public class Member { 
    public int ID {get; set; }
    public string MemberUserID {get; set; }

    public virtual MemberUser MemberUser { get; set; }
}
```

In my Context, I have this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasRequired(m => m.MemberUser)
                             .WithOptional(u => u.MemberInfo);
```

So, the MemberUser and Member should be able to navigate to and from each other using the MemberUser's ID property and Member's MemberUserID property.

However, when my Database is created, it has an additional column "MemberUser_Id" instead of using my MemberUserID that I specified. How do I make it use "MemberUserID" that I specified?

I've tried using a few combination so of the ForiegnKey Data Annotation, but keeps on getting this error:
Member_MemberUser_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Member_MemberUser_Source' in relationship 'Member_MemberUser'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: please tell me clearly what u need to do now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether i understood you right or not, but i'l do my best to help.
(I'l assume that you work with code first migration)

If you want to make a one-to-one relation, why not try to make a standalone entity for your info which will have a foreign key for the user entity and that foreign key will be annotated as the primary key of the entity?

Another way is why just not add whatever attributes you like to the Application User entity and work with it?

In any case i might have misunderstood your purpose, so please feel free to explain further since your post is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yea, the idea was to have a foreign key for the user entity that will be anotated as the primary key too, thus making it a real one to one relationship.. However, due to some design flaw previously, the Member table has its ID as int, and now has many other dependencies on that. Thus, it was too late to change

Comment: What I need is basically a way to navigate between Member and MemberUser table using a reference.. The reference is MemberUser's ID column and Member's MemberUserID column..

Comment: So the purpose is that a user would be able to see other user's profile? If not, and you just want the user's info be in a different table, you can use the ApplicationUser Entity and add any attributes you like. In any case, you can try take drastic measures and recreate your db (Drop DB and Migrations, and rerun the whole thing). It fixed issues for several EF i had during my projects (That is of course if you don't have any data that you couldn't reconstruct).